# Where can I find replacement light bulbs for this bathroom?

Tags: lighting, light, light-bulb

[This bathroom had two dead lightbulbs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Lur8.jpg), and two other ones are starting to become dimmer.

However, their shape is rather peculiar, and I've had no luck when looking for an identical replacement online.

**Can these bulbs be replaced by a similar-looking equivalent, and which one?**

Comment: 60G25 is a 60w globe, 25 eighths of an inch. (3.125" diameter). Most lamps are measured in eighths, for instance F32T8 fluorescents are 32 watt 1" Tube, 65R30 are reflector 3.75", 60A19 was a basic 60w  2.375" standard light bulb.

Answer (score 2):

As your last photo notes, it’s a G25 bulb, also known as a globe bulb. Your particular ones are compact fluorescent but they were originally incandescent and are also available in LED, which I’d recommend.

A simple web search for “G25 light bulb” returns many matches, including Home Depot and Lowe’s.

Comment: Exactly correct, +1. "G" indicates globe shape, "25" is an indicator of physical size/diameter - 25 1/8ths of an inch (3 1/8"). Make sure you select the correct type/size base ("medium" base being the common...)

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the bulbs with new LEDs that you like.  You could for example use these G25 Edison LEDs or something else you like better.  Anything with a standard base and short neck will be fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could replace them with just about anything.  It's a standard socket.  Otherwise you just need the "type" on the base like the other post stated to get the same shape.  Matching the exact light color may prove difficult though if you care about that.  You can try to find 2700k fluorescent g25 bulbs to get the closest match.  An led will probably look a bit different for color than your current fluorescent bulbs even with the same color rating.

If you want to start swapping them out or just replace them all then led often lasts longer and uses less electricity so switching could be a good idea.  The k number on the bulb is the color of the light.  2700k is very soft white (yellowish), at about 6,000k the light takes on a bluish tint and seems dimmer again, and in the middle is variations on whiter, brighter seeming light than the 2700k.  I hate that dingy yellow so I'd probably just swap them all out for some cool white (~3,500k) led version of the g25 shape but it's a matter of preference.